# Crashlytics.logException is not working on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Fatal exceptions are shown in `Firebase` dashboard. But non-fatal exceptions are not shown in `Firebase crashlytics` and `Firebase crash reporting`. I restarted app several times after non-fatal crash, but still there's no crash in `Firebase dashboard`. 
dependencies are:-

```
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

Below is the code to for non-fatal exception.

```
try {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Fake IndexOutOfBoundsException");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the date was not set correctly. The date was set till yesterday's date.

Comment: I am facing similar issue..How you know that date issue and is that resolved?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(e);
```

Comment: May be taking some time to reflect the crash in dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

> To reduce your users' network traffic, Crashlytics batches logged exceptions together and sends them the next time the app launches. If you don't see logged exceptions in your Crashlytics web dashboard, try restarting your app!

from:
https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions